# How to open lightbox on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, lightbox

I would like to use this nice gallery for bootstrap when I click onto a specific location on an image : http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/

It works really fine but now on another page I'd like to open the gallery at the page load, without a click. Is it possible ?
Here my code :

```html
<area target="" alt="" title="" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/....&rel=0" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="hidden-images" coords="1,0,2,718,215,714,211,841,1190,841,1187,1" shape="poly">
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1):

OK so I have the answer here :

```html
<area id="#open-youtube" target="" alt="" title="" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/....&rel=0" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="hidden-images" coords="1,0,2,718,215,714,211,841,1190,841,1187,1" shape="poly">

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#open-youtube').ready(function (e) {
                $('#open-youtube').ekkoLightbox();
});
</script>
```

I hope it will help somehone.